# How polar researchers were able to pinpoint the south magnetic pole in 1900s?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am reading a few books on polar explorations done in 1900s and one of the aim of these explorers was to locate the south magnetic pole. I wonder how able to pinpoint the location of south magnetic pole. What kind of equipment were used at that time? Any picture and their data will be helpful.

Comment: How does a compass work at the equator? What would a compass do at one of the poles?